# How can I split the output of "ps -ef" into "row output"

Tags: bash, shell

How can I split the output of "ps -ef" into "row output".   One of the problems I am having is how to handle the "gpm -m /dev/input/mice -t exps2" as a single item during string tokenization.

If 'ps -ef' output is like this:

```
root      3410     1  0 Jun17 ?        00:00:00 gpm -m /dev/input/mice -t exps2
root      3424     1  0 Jun17 ?        00:00:00 crond
root      3488     1  0 Jun17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/atd
```

Then, how can I pretty print it so it looks like:

```
1:
root
3410
00:00:00
gpm -m /dev/input/mice -t exps2

2: 
root
3424
00:00:00
crond

3: 
root
3488
00:00:00
/usr/sbin/atd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
let i=0
while read line; do
  read user pid _ _ _ _ time command <<<"$line"
  if [ "$user" != UID ]; then # skip header line
    printf "%s\n" $((++i)): "$user" "$pid" "$time" "$command" ""
  fi
done < <(ps -ef)
```

You could also read the line directly into an array of fields in the first place with `read -a`, but then the command comes in as multiple elements and it's a little more work to combine it back into a single word.

Comment: This answer is incredible.  I never would have thought of this and I am enlightened.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following shell snippet

```
OIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
i=0
for line in `ps -ef`; do
    echo "$i:"
    echo $line | cut -d' ' -f1
    echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2
    echo $line | cut -d' ' -f7
    echo $line | cut -d' ' -f8-
    (( i++ ))
done
IFS=$OIFS
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
ps -ef | awk -v OFS="\n" '{ for (i=8;i<=NF;i++) line = (line ? line FS : "") $i; print NR ":", $1, $2, $7, line, ""; line = "" }'
```

Results:

```
1:
root
3410
00:00:00
gpm -m /dev/input/mice -t exps2

2:
root
3424
00:00:00
crond

3:
root
3488
00:00:00
/usr/sbin/atd
```

Comment: Pretty good answer but I like how Mark Reed wrote the script without any other utilities except for 'ps'.